# Ruby on Rails: create a hash for select menu from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have an array:

> @positions = ["external_footer", "external_top_menu",
>   "external_side_menu"]

I want to create a select box so it produces humanized value for option and original value for option value. So i want something like that:

```
<option value="external_footer">External Footer</option>
```

Right now i am doing it like so:

> = f.input :position, collection: @positions.collect{|position| { position => position.humanize}}

But it does not work.

Comment: Mind explaining how it does not work? Does it crash or display nothing or not humanize the text? Also are you using SimpleForm?

Comment: It does not give me an error, i just produces "external_footer" => External Footer as a text for select box...

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution:

> = f.input :position, collection: @positions.collect{|p| [ p.humanize, p ] }

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `@positions` in your controller? , if not, i think you should change:

```
positions = ["external_footer", "external_top_menu", "external_side_menu"]
```

to:

```
@positions = ["external_footer", "external_top_menu", "external_side_menu"]
```

And you can try this:

```
= f.input :position, collection: @positions.collect { |position| position.humanize }
```

Comment: Sorry i did a typo in my example code, i have "positions" variable set as global.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your syntax may be wrong - you have one extra pair of braces. Try `= f.input :position, collection: @positions.collect{|position| position.humanize}` 
or `= f.input :position, collection: @positions.collect(&:humanize)`

Assuming you're using SimpleForm, it's possible it doesn't know what method to call for the option label and value. Try passing the `:label_method` and `:value_method` explicitly, or pass `humanize` as a lambda, as described [here](http://simple-form.plataformatec.com.br/#usage/collections).